# Top List with three parts

Tags: php, mysql

I have this cod for my TOP LIST

```
$pos=0;

$upit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_entries ORDER BY vote DESC");

while ($sms = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
$pos++;
$data = unserialize($sms['data']);
echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
}
```

- data[1] is NAME
- data[2] is SURNAME
- sms[vote] is NUMBER OF VOTES

And these top list look like this

```
1 Novak Djokovic 50
2 Rafael Nadal 35
3 Roger Federer 30
4 Andre Agassi 26
5 Pete Sampras 22
6 Andy Murray 19
7 Chris Evert 13
8 Michael Chang 10
9 Andy Roddick 7
10 Boris Becker 5
11 Björn Borg 1
```

And I want my top list look like this

> ```
> // FINALIST // Limit first 4 // green font
>         1 Novak Djokovic 50 
>         2 Rafael Nadal 35 
>         3 Roger Federer 30 
>         4 Andre Agassi 26 
> // OTHERS // All other except first 4 and last 2 // black font
>         5 Pete Sampras 22 
>         6 Andy Murray 19 
>         7 Chris Evert 13 
>         8 Michael Chang 10 
>         9 Andy Roddick 7        
> // FALL OUT // Limit last 2 // red font
>         10 Boris Becker 5
>         11 Björn Borg 1
> ```

I hope you understand me and that someone knows how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: So, you have the data correct, you just want to format it differently based on their score?

Comment: Are you outputting to HTML? Is this actually an HTML/CSS question?

Comment: Yes, cod is ok and work.  I just want to outputting a different look.

Comment: for font color i use html. The primary issue is how to divide the table into three parts?

Comment: @BalkanLifestyle, I have given you the solution, first find out number of return from sql query then you can divide it into 3 section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$pos=0;
$upit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_entries ORDER BY vote DESC");
$max = mysql_num_rows($upit);
$max = $max - 2;
while ($sms = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
    $pos++;
    $data = unserialize($sms['data']);
    if ($pos < 5){
        // first 4 in different color. Green Font
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    } elseif ($pos <= $max) {
        //from 5th to 3rd last (left 2 from bottom) in different color. Black Font
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    } else {
        // last 2 in different color. Red Font
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're wanting something like this... you can then change your `echo` code based on how you want to format it.

```
$pos=0;

$upit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_entries ORDER BY vote DESC");

while ($sms = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
    $pos++;
    $data = unserialize($sms['data']);
    if ($pos < 5){
        // finalist format (1-4)
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    } elseif ($pos > 9) {
        // format fallout users (9+)
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    } else {
        // format other (5-9)
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    }
}
```

Comment: This cod is ok... Only one thing does not work well for fallout.
Number of persons in the Top List is constantly increasing.
When the list increases, thus increasing and number of fallout persons. d I need limit it to be the last 2 persons for fallout.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first 4 in different color, from 5th to 3rd last (left 2 from bottom) in different color and last 2 in different color.

So, first find total number of row from SQL query so that we can put 2nd if condition.

```
$pos=0;
$upit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_entries ORDER BY vote DESC");
$max = mysql_num_rows($upit);
$max = $max - 2;
while ($sms = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
    $pos++;
    $data = unserialize($sms['data']);
    if ($pos < 5){
        // first 4 in different color. Green Font
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    } elseif ($pos <= $max) {
        //from 5th to 3rd last (left 2 from bottom) in different color. Black Font
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    } else {
        // last 2 in different color. Red Font
        echo "  ".$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms[vote]." ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need HTML output, here is a **very crude** way of doing it:

```
<?php


$pos = 0;

if( $upit = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM wp_entries ORDER BY vote DESC" ) )
{
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $upit );
    if( $num_rows > 0 )
    {
        echo '<ul>';

        while ($sms = mysql_fetch_array($upit))
        {
            $pos++;

            $style = "";

            if ($pos < 5)
            {
                $style = ' style="color:#00FF00;"';
            }
            elseif ($pos <= ($num_rows-2))
            {
                $style = ' style="color:#000000;"';
            }
            else
            {
                $style = ' style="color:#FF0000;"';
            }


            $data = unserialize($sms['data']);
            echo '  <li'.$style.'>'.$pos." ".$data[1]['value']." ".$data[2]['value']."  ".$sms['vote']."<li>";
        }

        echo '<ul>';
    }
}
?>
```